# Perl modules not installing. sh: 1: gzip: Exec format error

Tags: perl, cpan

I am getting issues when trying to install Perl modules on Ubuntu running on Windows 10.
I am not sure the best way to post the output, I am guessing maybe as "code"

```
$ cpan HTTP::Tiny
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading '/home/user/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sun, 06 Nov 2022 23:29:01 GMT
Running install for module 'HTTP::Tiny'
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DA/DAGOLDEN/HTTP-Tiny-0.082.tar.gz
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DA/DAGOLDEN/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for /home/user/.cpan/sources/authors/id/D/DA/DAGOLDEN/HTTP-Tiny-0.082.tar.gz ok
sh: 1: /usr/bin/gzip: Exec format error
/usr/bin/tar: This does not look like a tar archive
/usr/bin/tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
Uncompressed /home/user/.cpan/sources/authors/id/D/DA/DAGOLDEN/HTTP-Tiny-0.082.tar.gz successfully
Using Tar:/usr/bin/tar xf "HTTP-Tiny-0.082.tar":
Untarred HTTP-Tiny-0.082.tar successfully
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Package contains both files[HTTP-Tiny-0.082.tar] and directories[HTTP-Tiny-0.082]; not recognized as a perl package, giving up
Configuring D/DA/DAGOLDEN/HTTP-Tiny-0.082.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Running make for D/DA/DAGOLDEN/HTTP-Tiny-0.082.tar.gz
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
  DAGOLDEN/HTTP-Tiny-0.082.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
```

I am really suck on how to fix this, I have been scratching my head for a few days now and any assistance would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is Ubuntu running as WSL? Could you post the Ubuntu version & cpan version?

The first error seems to be with gzip, could you post its version as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the log it seems to be an issue specifically with Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL1:

`sh: 1: gzip: Exec format error`

see: [gzip from Ubuntu Jammy doesn't execute #8219](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8219)

You could install an earlier version of `gzip` via. `apt` that works well – however the best route would be to [update to WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install#upgrade-version-from-wsl-1-to-wsl-2), as it has many benefits and it won't have this issue.

See the [comparison page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions) including some rare cases where you might want to stay on WSL 1.

Comment: [Comparing WSL 1 and WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions)

Comment: Brilliant ,this worked an absolute treat, I really appreciate this answer!